# Use the unallocated space to expand Windows (Ntfs Partition)

Tags: gparted

Here is a screenshot of what i see in Gparted..

[image]

What can i do to expand my ntfs with that 20gb unallocated space?
I see no available options when i right click the unallocated space..

Comment: When you selected, there is `Resize/Move` button on menu bar behind `delete` click that, another resizing window will comeup, try to resize draging the spaces.

Comment: The unallocated space is not right next to the ntfs partition, there is a 68GB ext4 partition in between, and also, the unallocated space is inside the extended partition. In short, you can't just expand /dev/sda2, becaus there is nowhere to expand it to.

Comment: @mikewhatever please consider making that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand the NTFS partition, the free space must follow it.  Right now it is in the middle of your extended partition.  To fix this, you will need to move the ext4 partition to the right, then resize the start of the extended partition to the right, *then* you can expand the NTFS partition.

Note that moving partitions takes a very, very long time, and if something goes wrong ( power goes out ), you will trash your data, so make a backup first.

Comment: Worked, completed and exactly 2 hours. Thanks!